# rspec: testing cookie options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec

I'd like to test if my Rails controller sets a valid options (in this case `path`) for cookie. How could I do it with RSpec?

My code:

```
#Controller
def action
  #(...)
  cookies[:name] = { value:cookie_data,
                     path: cookie_path }
  #(...)
end

#spec 
it "sets cookie path" do
  get 'action'
  #I'd like do to something like that
  response.cookies['name'].path.should == '/some/path' 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, but it seems to be a kind of hacking. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
it "sets cookie path" do
  get 'action'
  match = response.header["Set-Cookie"].match(/path=(.*);?/)
  match.should_not be_nil
  match[1].should == '/some/path'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying unsuccessfully to get CGI::Cookie.parse to do the right thing, I wound up rolling my own parser. It's quite simple:

```
def parse_set_cookie_header(header)
  kv_pairs = header.split(/\s*;\s*/).map do |attr|
    k, v = attr.split '='

    [ k, v || nil ]
  end

  Hash[ kv_pairs ]
end
```

Here's a sampling of the results it produces:

**Cookie creation:**

```
IN: "signup=VALUE_HERE; path=/subscriptions; secure; HttpOnly"
OUT: {"signup"=>"VALUE_HERE", "path"=>"/subscriptions", "secure"=>nil, "HttpOnly"=>nil}
```

**Cookie deletion:**

```
IN: "signup=; path=/subscriptions; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000; secure; HttpOnly"
OUT: {"signup"=>nil, "path"=>"/subscriptions", "max-age"=>"0", "expires"=>"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000", "secure"=>nil, "HttpOnly"=>nil}
```

And here's an example spec to go along with it:

```
describe 'the Set-Cookie header' do
  let(:value) { 'hello world' }

  let(:signup_cookie) do
    parse_set_cookie_header response.header['Set-Cookie']
  end

  before do
    get :index, :spec => 'set_signup_cookie'
  end

  it 'has a payload set for :signup' do
    expect(signup_cookie['signup']).to be_present
  end

  it 'has the right path' do
    expect(signup_cookie['path']).to eq '/subscriptions'
  end

  it 'has the secure flag set' do
    expect(signup_cookie).to have_key 'secure'
  end

  it 'has the HttpOnly flag set' do
    expect(signup_cookie).to have_key 'HttpOnly'
  end

  it 'is a session cookie (i.e. it has no :expires)' do
    expect(signup_cookie).not_to have_key 'expires'
  end

  it 'has no max-age' do
    expect(signup_cookie).not_to have_key 'max-age'
  end
end
```

Comment: i love you <3 . This way you can test the expiration date of a cookie in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several of the solutions offered here and in similar threads. The only one that has worked well for me is to inspect the Set-Cookie header, something like this:

```
it 'expires cookie in 15 minutes' do
  travel_to(Date.new(2016, 10, 25))
  post 'favorites', params: { flavor: 'chocolate' }
  travel_back

  details = 'favorite=chocolate; path=/; expires=Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:15:00 GMT; HttpOnly'
  expect(response.header['Set-Cookie']).to eq details
end
```

This is a bit brittle, in that other, non-critical attributes of the cookie may break this string. But it does keep you out of Rails internals, and lets you check several attributes at once. (Noting that's an anti-pattern rspec!)

If you only care about one attribute, you could match it like this:

```
  expect(response.header['Set-Cookie']).to match(
    /favorite=chocolate.*; expires=Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:15:00 GMT/
  )
```